# ngFor in ngFor set active class on click?

Tags: angular

```
 <div *ngFor="let position of positions" [ngClass]="{active :  position===selected.row }">


    <div *ngFor="let item of items[position], let i = index"   class="flow-one-item" (click)="selectItem(item)"> </div> </div>
```

I have ngFor in ngFor what i want is to set active class on second ngFor on click. Any suggestion how can i do that??
I tried to add `selectedItem == item` but its not working,i think because of this `items[position]`.

Comment: Can you make a small StackBlitz with your code, it would be easier to help?

Comment: Its difficult to answer from such unclear description

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are selecting the item of the main array "Positions" you have to change your code of the click event to sent the current position, not the item. Something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let position of positions" 
     [ngClass]="{active :  position===selected.row }">


     <div *ngFor="let item of items[position], let i = index"     
           class="flow-one-item" (click)="selectItem(position)"></div> 
</div>
```